# zooming sends me 'inside' the model

Tags: sketchup

I'm trying to adjust a little detail on a project, but when I'm zooming to get closer to the model, I kinda "get inside" the model, like I was too closer and I can't adjust anything at all...

Is there a way to adjust the zoom level?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. I think your question might be about one of these two: **A)** Your camera view is stuck in inside the model. `Try (Ctrl+shift+E) - The tool icon is like a magnifying class with arrows pointing outwards` **B)** You are not able to zoom in small enough increments and you always end up zooming too far or not close enough. `Try the zoom tool (Z) and drag the cursor up and down to zoom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My comment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35100/zooming-sends-me-inside-the-model#comment48490_35100) as an answer:

[image] Zoom tool <kbd>Z</kbd> - This can be used to zoom in and out by clicking and dragging with the mouse cursor up and down.

`This is very precise method of zooming. You can also you can control the speed with your mouse.`

---

Zoom extents <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> - Fits your model into the view.

`Handy if you zoom in too far, for example.`

---

Zoom window <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+W</kbd> - With this tool you can zoom to a specific part of the model by drawing a rectangle in that area.

`Good for quickly zooming into specific parts of the model.`

---

You can find all of the above from the top menu `Camera > ...`

Comment: I believe it is called "clipping"?

Answer (score 0):

Zooming is relative to the focus of your cursor: you should aim your cursor at the part you're trying to zoom in on.
If you're working on a detail and zoom with your cursor focussed on the background, you'll find that you will zoom past the object very fast.